# PostgreSQL: su - Authentication failure in postgresql

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I have installed PostgreSQL 10.6, Postgres client and Pgadmin 4.

I just created a new Rails application and I used Postgresql as the database for the application, only for me to get a message saying

> su: Authentication Failure

each time I try to login into the postgres account to create the development database for the rails application.

I have tried a couple of times to fix this issue, I have also attempted to solve by trying out several solutions that I found online, but all to no avail.

**What should I do? I need some assistance.**

Answer (score 26, accepted):

To solve this simply follow the solution below

**Change the password for a user**

Login to the server where PostgreSQL is installed.

Next, switch to the root user:

```
sudo su -
```

Log in to `psql` using the `postgres` database login role, connecting to the `postgres` database:

```
psql postgres postgres
```

Issue the `\password` command to alter the password of the user:

```
\password my-user
```

**Note**: This will prompt you to enter a new password twice.

And then exit the `psql` prompt:

```
\q
```

Afterwhich you can exit and then test the password using the command below to login to the `postgres` database:

```
psql -U my-user -W postgres
```

**Change the password for the postgres user**

If you do not know the password for the postgres user, run the psql command from the postgres user account:

```
sudo passwd postgres
```

**Note**: This will prompt you to enter a new password twice.

And then exit the `psql` prompt:

```
\q
```

**To test and confirm** the password change or setup, run the psql command from the postgres user account:

```
su - postgres
```

Enter the new password that you just setup.

That's all

**I hope this helps.**

Answer (score 1):

Try to use the command:

```
sudo bash
```

then enter your users password else of your Mac or of any linux distribution
instead of using `su`